# How do I lookup username using first and last name

Tags: linux, unix

How do I lookup username using first and last name?

Something which does the reverse of `getent passwd <username>`

`finger` is taking forever and doesn't display exact match. i.e it displays all logins with same first name or same last name

Answer (score 1):

For passwd entries like

```
pulse:x:117:124:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
```

You'd extract the 5th `:`-delimited field, extract the first `,`-delimited field of that, and check if that equals the first name followed by a blank followed by the last name.

```
firstname=PulseAudio
lastname=daemon
getent passwd | awk -F: -vfirst="$firstname" -vlast="$lastname" '{
  split($5,name,",");
  if(name[1]==(first " " last)) {
    print $1;
  }
}'
```

If you want the check to be case-insensitive, you can add calls to `tolower()` on each side of the comparison.